# Limit of the derivative of a composite function

Tags: functions, continuity

Consider two anti-symmetric strictly monotonic $C^\infty$ functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto(-1,1)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\mapsto(-1,1)$, with $f(y)<g(y)$ for all $y>0$. Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=1$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=0$. Also, $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{1-g(x)}{1-f(x)}=0$. Consider a composite function $h(x) = g(f^{-1}(x))$. The goal is to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} h'(x)=0$.

My thoughts so far:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        \lim_{x\rightarrow1} h'(x) 
        &= \lim_{x\rightarrow1} \left[g\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)\right]' \\
        &= \lim_{x\rightarrow1} \left[g'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)\cdot (f^{-1})'(x)\right]\\
        &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right) \cdot  \lim_{x\rightarrow1} (f^{-1})'(x) \\
        &= g'\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f^{-1}(x)\right) \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow1} (f^{-1})'(x) \\
        &= \lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} g'(y) \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow1} (f^{-1})'(x) \\
        &= \lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} g'(y) \cdot \lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{f'(z)} \\
        &= \lim_{y,z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{g'(y)}{f'(z)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
After this, I am not so sure how to show the limit of two functions with two different variables. Please correct me if I am wrong. Then, $f(x)$ converges much faster than $g(x)$, due to the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{1-g(x)}{1-f(x)}=0$, then the limit $\lim_{y,z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{g'(y)}{f'(z)}$ goes to zero. Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} h'(x)=0$ holds.

Comment: Without even looking: there is no such thing as $g'$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for your comment. Could you please specifically point out where this $g'$ does not exist? For example you could consider $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} atan(x/2)$, and $g(x)=atan(x)$.

Comment: Or, for example, you could not: that is how axiomatic reasoning works. The point is in the first two lines, where you wrote down the hypothesis and said that $g$ is only continuous.

Comment: You haven't.${}$

Comment: @Gae.S.Done. My main question is actually how to solve the last limit, which has two different variables for $g'$ and $f'$. Could we use quotient rule for the limit, and write them as one variable? e.g. is it true that $\lim_{y,z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g'(y)}{f'(z)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$.